# GitHub Actions Workflow: fatal: invalid reference: better-page Error: Process completed with exit code 128

Tags: git, yaml, github-actions, workflow

Here's my code:

```yaml
name: Copy files to another branch

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - better-page
    workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
    contents: write
    pages: write
    id-token: write

concurrency:
    group: "pages"
    cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
    copy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout better-page
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
              with:
                  ref: better-page

            - name: Copy files 1
              run: |
                  git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
                  git config --global user.email "action@github.com"
                  git fetch origin better-page:better-page --update-head-ok
                  # rsync -r --exclude=.git --exclude=.github --exclude=about-me --exclude=node_modules --exclude=simplified . simplified/
                  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'simplified' -exec cp -r {} simplified \;
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "create simplified directory"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin better-page # push to remote branch

            - name: Checkout gh-pages
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
              with:
                  ref: gh-pages
                  path: gh-pages

            - name: Copy files 2
              run: |
                  git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
                  git config --global user.email "action@github.com"
                  git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages --update-head-ok
                  git checkout better-page -- simplified
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "copy files from better-page"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin gh-pages # push to remote branch
              working-directory: gh-pages
```

I want to

1. Copy all files in root of `better-page` branch into a folder called `simplified`.
2. Checkout that folder into the `gh-pages` branch

But the error is preventing me. [`Copy files 1` runs without error](https://cdn.nekonyan.fun/opera_aNqDpRkD4h.png), but it really copy the files into the folder? It does create an empty commit `create simplified directory` with [one file changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpPiM.png) and no new files are created or copied into the folder.

How do I fix these? What should I change to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: In your second checkout, only the `gh-pages` branch is being checkout out, not `better-page`. You need to fetch `better-page` also if you need it. Use `fetch-depth: 0` instead of `ref` during checkout to fetch the complete git history.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to check out again into a subdirectory -- if you're confident your previous commit did what you wanted it to do, it's safe to immediately jump to the `git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages --update-head-ok` -- depending on what artifacts you expect to still be laying around, `git clean -fx`, then carry on from `git checkout better-page -- simplified`

That is to say

```yaml
            - name: Checkout gh-pages
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
              with:
                  ref: gh-pages
                  path: gh-pages

            - name: Copy files 2
              run: |
                  git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
                  git config --global user.email "action@github.com"
                  git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages --update-head-ok
                  git checkout better-page -- simplified
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "copy files from better-page"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin gh-pages # push to remote branch
              working-directory: gh-pages
```

Could instead be

```yaml
            - name: Copy files 2
              run: |
                  git fetch origin gh-pages:gh-pages --update-head-ok
                  git clean -fx
                  git checkout better-page -- simplified
                  git add .
                  git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "copy files from better-page"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
                  git push origin gh-pages # push to remote branch
```

But I'm not sure your `cp -r {} simplified` is doing exactly what you want it to do. Have you tested it locally? It would appear you're asking it to recursively copy every file onto the same file named `simplified`. If a folder already existed with that name with tracked contents, then `cp` would see it as "copy into this folder", but if the folder doesn't exist yet (which it appears not to) it's just going to iteratively write over a file with that name. And it appears this is what it's already done and checked in because it's showing you a diff of a file with that name -- i.e. those changes would be the changes of the last file it copied over that filename.

From the description that you only want the root folder's immediate descendents to be put into the `simplified` folder, I would say you'll need to checkout the `better-page` branch, remove that file, and add a folder with that name, and have at least one file that you commit in it so it's tracked, then you'd need only `cp {} simplified` (no need to recurse if you're already iterating over the results of the `find`, and only copying one level deep that you got from `-maxdepth 1`).

Comment: Hi Skenvy, thank you so much! The `cp` part worked, and you were right. I had to follow your instructions to properly copy. 

However, the files aren't getting copied over to the `gh-pages` branch. I even tried removing the `git clean -fx` line, but nothing is being copied or committed. I used the same code replacement as you provided. By the way, I'm trying to copy *from* `better-page` *to* `gh-pages`. So from my googling, shouldn't we be in `gh-pages` as a working directory first?